# How to mock remote_ip in AsyncHTTPTestCase

Tags: unit-testing, tornado

My application uses RequestHandler.request.remote_ip and I want to mock the value in my test case which is a subclass of AsyncHTTPTestCase. What is the most elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

In your AsyncHTTPTestCase subclass, override get_httpserver_options to add the xheaders option (`def get_httpserver_options(self): return dict(xheaders=True)`), and then pass `headers={'X-Real-IP': '123.45.67.89'}` to your fetch calls.